# How to ignore base class JsonConverter when deserializing derived classes?

Tags: c#, json.net

I have an abstract base class:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(Converter))]
public abstract class TextComponent {
    ...
    public bool Bold { get; set; }
    public TextComponent[] Extra { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

And more classes which inherits from it. One of those classes is `StringComponent`:

```
public sealed class StringComponent : TextComponent
{
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public StringComponent(string text)
    {
        Text = text;
    }
}
```

`Converter`, which is a `JsonConverter` applied to `TextComponent` looks like this:

```
private sealed class Converter : JsonConverter
{
    ....

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue,
        JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var tok = JToken.Load(reader);
        switch (tok)
        {
            ...
            case JObject x:
                var dic = (IDictionary<string, JToken>) x;
                if (dic.ContainsKey("text")) return x.ToObject<StringComponent>();
                ...
            ...
        }
    }
    ...
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => objectType == typeof(TextComponent);
}
```

**The problem**:

```
var str = "{\"text\":\"hello world\"}";
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TextComponent>(str);
// this doesn't work either:
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<StringComponent>(str);
```

This goes into an infinite "loop" eventually resulting in a `StackOverflow`, because when calling `DeserializeObject<Stringcomponent>` or `ToObject<StringComponent>`, the `JsonConverter` of the base class (the `Converter`) is used which again calls those methods. This is not the desired behavior. When serializing derived classes, they should not be using base class's `JsonConverter`.  If you look at `CanConvert` method of the `Converter`, I'm also only allowing it for `TextComponent` only, not for any of it's derived classes.

So how do I fix this?

Comment: Duplicate: [How to call JsonConvert.DeserializeObject and disable a JsonConverter applied to a base type via `[JsonConverter]`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45547123/3744182).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to remove the [JsonConvert]-attribute from your base class? In my example I invoke my "custom" converter manually: 
https://github.com/Code-Inside/Samples/blob/b635580a4966b1b77c93a8b682389c6cf06d2da6/2015/JsonConvertIssuesWithBaseClasses/JsonConvertIssuesWithBaseClasses/Program.cs#L36-L79

Comment: Thanks for replying :D. That + passing the serializer to ToObject does fix the problem. But I wonder why the Attribute messed up :/

Comment: Theory: The serializer checks for the JsonConvert attribute to select the "right" serializer and then you are stuck in a loop, which would explain the StackOverflow.

Comment: Yeah but my JsonConverter's CanConvert method specifically allows only the base class. Moreover, the attribute is only applied to the BaseClass. So I don't see why it should follow over to derived classes. 
I guess it's a bug?

Answer (score 5):

You can set the converter on the sub class contract to null;

```
    public override bool CanWrite => false;
    public override bool CanRead => true;

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (objectType == typeof(BaseClass))
        {
            JObject item = JObject.Load(reader);
            if (item["isClass2"].Value<bool>())
            {
                return item.ToObject<ChildClass2>(serializer);
            }
            else
            {
                return item.ToObject<ChildClass1>(serializer);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(objectType).Converter = null;
            return serializer.Deserialize(reader, objectType);
        }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```