# StackOverflow when using JObject.FromValue

Tags: c#, json, json.net, event-sourcing

A StockOverflowException is being caused by the code below, inside the `WriteJson` method at the call to `JObject.FromObject(value)`. It recalls the `WriteJson` method.

How can I rewrite the AggregateEventConverter to avoid the recursive stack overflow problem?

And because I know somebody's going to ask, the code is written this way because events are written permanently to a stream and need to be able to be deserialized accurately years later after other coders have refactored the names of old event classes. For example, they may change `class AppleFellOffTree` to `class AppleFellOffTree_v001`, deprecating it but keeping it in the assembly for the purpose of deserializing old events. The `AggregateEventTypeId` attribute helps deserialize json into the correct classes, so long as coders keep those attributes intact while shifting/refactoring the event classes.

Newtonsoft's own TypeNameHandling feature doesn't help accurately deserialize classes whose names have been refactored.

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var e1 = new AppleFellOffTree {
            At = TimeStamp.Now,
            Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
            VersionNumber = 21,
        };
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(e1);
        var e2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AggregateEvent>(json);
    }
}

[Serializable]
[JsonConverter(typeof(AggregateEventConverter))]
public class AggregateEvent {
    public string EventName => GetType().Name;
    public Guid Id;
    public int VersionNumber;
    public TimeStamp At;
}

[AggregateEventTypeId("{44B9114E-085F-4D19-A142-0AC76573602B}")]
public class AppleFellOffTree : AggregateEvent {
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
public class AggregateEventTypeIdAttribute : Attribute {
    public readonly Guid Id;
    public AggregateEventTypeIdAttribute(string guid) {
        Id = Guid.Parse(guid);
    }
}

public class AggregateEventConverter : JsonConverter {

    public override bool CanRead => true;
    public override bool CanWrite => true;
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => objectType == typeof(AggregateEvent) || objectType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(AggregateEvent));

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer) {
        if (null == value) {
            writer.WriteValue(value);
            return;
        }
        var jObject = JObject.FromObject(value);
        jObject.Add("$typeId", EventTypes.GetEventTypeId(value.GetType()));
        jObject.WriteTo(writer);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) {
        var jToken = JToken.ReadFrom(reader);
        if (jToken.Type != JTokenType.Object) {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        } else {
            var jObject = (JObject)jToken;
            var eventTypeId = (Guid)jObject.GetValue("$typeId");
            var eventType = EventTypes.GetEventType(eventTypeId);
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jToken.ToString(), eventType);
        }
    }
}

internal static class EventTypes {

    static readonly Dictionary<Guid, Type> Data = new Dictionary<Guid, Type>();

    static EventTypes() {

        var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();

        var eventTypes = assemblies.SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes()
            .Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(AggregateEvent)))
            .Where(t => !t.IsAbstract))
            .ToArray();

        // t is for eventType
        foreach (var t in eventTypes) {
            var id = GetEventTypeId(t);
            if (Data.ContainsKey(id))
                throw new Exception($"Duplicate {nameof(AggregateEventTypeIdAttribute)} value found on types '{t.FullName}' and '{Data[id].FullName}'");
            Data[id] = t;
        }
    }

    public static Type GetEventType(Guid eventTypeId) {
        return Data[eventTypeId];
    }

    public static Guid GetEventTypeId(Type type) {

        // a is for attribute
        var a = type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AggregateEventTypeIdAttribute), false)
            .Cast<AggregateEventTypeIdAttribute>()
            .FirstOrDefault();

        if (null == a)
            throw new Exception($"{nameof(AggregateEventTypeIdAttribute)} attribute does not exist on type {type.FullName}.");

        if (Guid.Empty == a.Id)
            throw new Exception($"{nameof(AggregateEventTypeIdAttribute)} attribute was not set to a proper value on type {type.FullName}");

        return a.Id;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<Guid, Type>> GetAll => Data;
}
```

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [How to call JsonConvert.DeserializeObject and disable a JsonConverter applied to a base type via `[JsonConverter]`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45547123/3744182).  The answers from [JSON.Net throws StackOverflowException when using `[JsonConvert()]`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29719509/3744182) might also work.

Comment: If the linked solutions don't work for you, please let me know where the problem is and I'll re-open the question.

Comment: @dbc Those links helped, thank you. Please re-open the question so I can post the code I ended up using.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/bboyle1234/46291a8c8d42f797405057844eeb4bda

Answer (score 1):

After reading the links provided in the comments, I came up with this solution.

https://gist.github.com/bboyle1234/46291a8c8d42f797405057844eeb4bda

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace Migratable {
    [JsonConverter(typeof(MigratableConverter))]
    public interface IMigratable {
    }

    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
    public class MigratableAttribute : Attribute {
        public readonly Guid Id;
        public MigratableAttribute(string guid) {
            Id = Guid.Parse(guid);
        }
    }

    public class MigratableConverter : JsonConverter {

        [ThreadStatic]
        static bool writeDisabled = false;

        [ThreadStatic]
        static bool readDisabled = false;

        public override bool CanRead => !readDisabled;
        public override bool CanWrite => !writeDisabled;
        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => typeof(IMigratable).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer) {
            try {
                writeDisabled = true;
                if (null == value) {
                    writer.WriteValue(value);
                } else {
                    var jObject = JObject.FromObject(value);
                    jObject.Add("$typeId", MigratableTypes.GetTypeId(value.GetType()));
                    jObject.WriteTo(writer);
                }
            } finally {
                writeDisabled = false;
            }
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) {
            try {
                readDisabled = true;
                var jObject = JToken.ReadFrom(reader) as JObject;
                if (null == jObject) return null;
                var typeId = (Guid)jObject.GetValue("$typeId");
                var type = MigratableTypes.GetType(typeId);
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jObject.ToString(), type);
            } finally {
                readDisabled = false;
            }
        }
    }

    internal static class MigratableTypes {

        static readonly Dictionary<Guid, Type> Data = new Dictionary<Guid, Type>();

        static MigratableTypes() {
            foreach (var type in GetIMigratableTypes()) {
                CheckIMigratableRules(type);
                Data[GetTypeId(type)] = type;
            }
        }

        static IEnumerable<Type> GetIMigratableTypes() {
            return AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                .SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes()
                .Where(t => typeof(IMigratable).IsAssignableFrom(t))
                .Where(t => !t.IsAbstract));
        }

        static void CheckIMigratableRules(Type type) {

            // Check for duplicate IMigratable identifiers
            var id = GetTypeId(type);
            if (Data.ContainsKey(id))
                throw new Exception($"Duplicate '{nameof(MigratableAttribute)}' value found on types '{type.FullName}' and '{Data[id].FullName}'.");

            // [DataContract] attribute is required, on EVERY class, not just base classes
            if (type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DataContractAttribute), false).Length == 0)
                throw new Exception($"'{nameof(IMigratable)}' objects are required to use the '[DataContract]' attribute. Class: '{type.FullName}'.");

            // Collect information about [DataMember] attributes on all fields and properties including inherited and private.
            var bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic;
            var fields = type.GetFields(bindingFlags).Where(f => null != f.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(DataMemberAttribute))).ToArray();
            var properties = type.GetProperties(bindingFlags).Where(p => null != p.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(DataMemberAttribute))).ToArray();
            var members = fields.Cast<MemberInfo>().Concat(properties.Cast<MemberInfo>())
                .Select(m => new {
                    Member = m,
                    DataMemberAttribute = (DataMemberAttribute)m.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(DataMemberAttribute))
                }).ToArray();

            // Check that DataMember names are explicitly set eg [DataMember(Name = "xx")]
            var noName = members.FirstOrDefault(m => !m.DataMemberAttribute.IsNameSetExplicitly);
            if (null != noName) {
                var message = $"'{nameof(IMigratable)}' objects are required to set DataMember names explicitly. Class: '{type.FullName}', Field: '{noName.Member.Name}'.";
                throw new Exception(message);
            }

            // Check that DataMember names are not accidentally duplicated.
            var duplicateName = members.GroupBy(m => m.DataMemberAttribute.Name).FirstOrDefault(g => g.Count() > 1);
            if (null != duplicateName) {
                throw new Exception($"Duplicate DataMemberName '{duplicateName.Key}' found on class '{type.FullName}'.");
            }
        }

        public static Type GetType(Guid typeId) {
            return Data[typeId];
        }

        public static Guid GetTypeId(Type type) {

            var a = type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MigratableAttribute), false)
                .Cast<MigratableAttribute>()
                .FirstOrDefault();

            if (null == a)
                throw new Exception($"'{nameof(MigratableAttribute)}' attribute does not exist on type '{type.FullName}'.");

            if (Guid.Empty == a.Id)
                throw new Exception($"'{nameof(MigratableAttribute)}' attribute was not set to a proper value on type '{type.FullName}'.");

            return a.Id;
        }
    }
}
```