# Deserialize varying JSONs to type hierarchy in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi, json-deserialization

In my ASP.NET 2.0 WebApi I do receive slighty different types of JSONs as POST body. The JSONs I may receive look like this

```
{
    "Version": "some string",
    "Session": "somestring",
    "Payload": {}
}
```

Payload then is one of these 3 variants:

```
{
    "tmestamp": "string"
}
```

or this:

```
{
    "tmestamp": "string",
    "name": "string"
}
```

or this:

```
{
    "tmestamp": "string",
    "status": number,
    "values": [
        number,
        number,
        ...
    ]
}
```

To have matching types I have created this hierarchy:

```
public class BaseRequest
{
    public string Version {get;set;}
    public string Session {get;set;}
    public BasePayload Playload {get;set;}
}

public class  BasePayload
{
    public DateTime timestamp {get;set;}
}

public class PayloadVariant1 : BasePayload
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
}

public class PayloadVariant2 : BasePayload
{
    public int Status {get;set;}
    public double[] Values {get;set}
}
```

The JSON format is defined by a third party vendor, so cannot be adjusted. I have defined my POST method as follows to get data:

```
[HttpPost]
public void Post([FromBody]BaseRequest content)
```

but `Payload` is always `BasePayload` and cannot be cast to a different type although the received data contains that content. Therefore I thought I may have to use Generics and define several posts:

```
// converted into a generic variant
public class BaseRequest<T> where T : BasePayload 
{
    public string Version {get;set;}
    public string Session {get;set;}
    public T Playload {get;set;}
}

[HttpPost]
public void Post([FromBody]BaseRequest<BasePayload> content) 

[HttpPost]
public void Post([FromBody]BaseRequest<PayloadVariant1> content)
```

But then I get this exception `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ActionSelector:Error: Request matched multiple actions resulting in ambiguity. Matching actions: SkillMediator.Controllers.MessagesController.Post (SkillMediator)`. I found that the Newtonsoft.JSON can be configured to read a variable `$type` from the JSON which contains the fully qualified name of the type as a hint for deserialization. But as already said the JSONs come from a public API which I cannot change.

Is there a way to have, based on the given JSON format, fully type-safe data structures in my ASP.NET Core code?

Comment: You can use a `JsonConverter` for this purpose.  Take a look at [Deserializing polymorphic json classes without type information using json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19307752/3744182) and [How to implement custom JsonConverter in JSON.NET to deserialize a List of base class objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8030538/3744182).  Of course you're not deserializing a list, just a single root object - but the same technique can be used by applying the converter to the base type.

Comment: If you do apply the converter to `BasePayload` you might need to use the trick from [How to call JsonConvert.DeserializeObject and disable a JsonConverter applied to a base type via `[JsonConverter]`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45547123/3744182).

Comment: Well you need to merge your Payloads into one class, then manually distinguish between them inside `Post` method.

Comment: @dbc Thanks I will review these posts and see if that works. @SeM This is the same suggestion as junkangli's anwser. But I do not want to do this because I would like to utilize polimorphism to handle the different kinds of requests. Merging them would result in `switch` or `if then` constructs to distinguish between them, which is bad coding style.

Answer (score 1):

You can merge all the variances into one model class:

```
public class BasePayload
{
    public DateTime? timestamp {get;set;}

    public string Name {get;set;}

    public int? Status {get;set;}
    public double[] Values {get;set}
}
```

But notice that I have used nullable types, so that properties not matched from the json will be left as null.

Comment: Yep that is the quick and dirty solution I use currently. But would be nice to be able to distinguish the structure based on the data type.