# I want JSON to "skip" deserializing JSON object into C# List<object> if JSON member is missing

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net, deserialization

I serialize a list of Interfaces into a JSON file that I deserialize later.
In one application, I am deserializing all types of JSON objects, but in another application I am **wanting to deserialize only one specific implementation of the Interface (Machine1)**. I want to keep the way I am serializing the data as-is, but change the deserialization code to SKIP any of the incorrect objects (JSON objects of a different type than I am interested)- my plan was to do this by checking if a Member variable is missing (if powerWatts is missing, then the data must be representing Machine2, therefore we should **skip deserializing this particular object (Machine2)** and instead deserialize the others in the array). How would I implement this using JSON.Net? MissingMemberHandling.Error throws an exception, so I don't think what would work for deserializing the rest of the list after seeing a missing property. MissingMemberHandling.Ignore leaves me with a property equal to 0, which is not correct.

Interface and Classes:

```
public interface IMachineInfo
{
    DateTime windowsTime { get; set; }
    DateTime irigTime { get; set; }
    string messageTypeFlag { get; }
    byte? sequenceNum { get; }
}  

public class Machine1 : IMachineInfo
{
    // Interface properties omitted for brevity
    public double powerWatts { get; set; }
    public double radiation { get; set; }
    public double current { get; set; }
}

public class Machine2 : IMachineInfo
{
    public double dbm { get; set; }
    public double magneticField { get; set; }
    public double frequency { get; set; }
}
```

Main:

```
// Serialization: get the interface and specific data into a collection that will be written to a file

IMachineInfo decoded = data[key].MachineDataDecoded;
dataConverted[key] = decoded;

//... more code 

//write JSON data to JSONData.txt

string jsondata = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataConverted.Values.ToArray(), Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore });

File.AppendAllText(Environment.CurrentDirectory + subDirectoryName + jsonFileName, jsondata);
```

App2 (deserialize the data)

```
// try to read the json, but I only want Machine1 data, skip anything in the json that is related to machine2

JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
    MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore
};
List<Machine1> ampData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Machine1>>(@"C/Path/jsonfile", settings);
```

Real JSON Data:

```
[
  {
    "windowsTime": "2019-01-14T18:47:55.8390256-06:00",
    "irigTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "messageTypeFlag": "Q",
    "sequenceNum": 0,
  },
  {
    "dbm": "66",
    "magneticField ": "8967",
    "frequency": "34500",
    "windowsTime": "2019-01-14T18:47:55.8390256-06:00",
    "irigTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "messageTypeFlag": "Q",
    "sequenceNum": 0,
  },
  {
    "powerWatts": "4000",
    "radiation": "67",
    "current": "2478",
    "windowsTime": "2019-01-14T18:47:55.8390256-06:00",
    "irigTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "messageTypeFlag": "Q",
    "sequenceNum": 0,
  },
  {
    "powerWatts": "4000",
    "radiation": "67",
    "current": "2478",
    "windowsTime": "2019-01-14T18:47:55.8390258-06:00",
    "irigTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "messageTypeFlag": "Q",
    "sequenceNum": 0,
   }
]
```

in my data above, only the 3rd and 4th element is of type Machine1, therefore I only want those object to be added to the list from json deserialization. The problem is, that **when I deserialize this now, `powerWatts = 0` for all 4 elements (not the behavior I want)**, even though it is only a valid property of the 3rd and 4th element. This is a problem since i can't just check if `powerWatts == 0` and remove it from my list since 0 could be a valid value in a real world situation. **I need to only deserialize Machine1 JSON objects**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could adopt and extend the general approach from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19308474/3744182) to *[Deserializing polymorphic json classes without type information using json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19307752/3744182)* or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45554062/3744182) to *[How to call JsonConvert.DeserializeObject and disable a JsonConverter applied to a base type via [JsonConverter]?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45547123/3744182)* by creating a [custom `JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) for `List<IMachineInfo>` that does the following:

1. Loads each array entry into a temporary `JToken`.
2. Tries to infer the item type from the parameters present.
3. Skips the array entry if the type cannot be inferred.

To do this, first introduce a generic base class converter as follows:

```
public abstract class JsonListItemTypeInferringConverterBase<TItem> : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanWrite { get { return false; } }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    protected abstract bool TryInferItemType(Type objectType, JToken json, out Type type);

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // Get contract information
        var contract = serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(objectType) as JsonArrayContract;
        if (contract == null || contract.IsMultidimensionalArray || objectType.IsArray)
            throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("Invalid array contract for {0}", objectType));

        if (reader.MoveToContent().TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;

        if (reader.TokenType != JsonToken.StartArray)
            throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("Expected {0}, encountered {1} at path {2}", JsonToken.StartArray, reader.TokenType, reader.Path));

        var collection = existingValue as IList<TItem> ?? (IList<TItem>)contract.DefaultCreator();

        // Process the collection items
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            switch (reader.TokenType)
            {
                case JsonToken.EndArray:
                    return collection;

                case JsonToken.Comment:
                    break;

                default:
                    {
                        var token = JToken.Load(reader);
                        Type itemType;
                        if (!TryInferItemType(typeof(TItem), token, out itemType))
                            break;
                        collection.Add((TItem)serializer.Deserialize(token.CreateReader(), itemType));
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
        // Should not come here.
        throw new JsonSerializationException("Unclosed array at path: " + reader.Path);
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(List<TItem>));
    }
}

public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    public static JsonReader MoveToContent(this JsonReader reader)
    {
        while ((reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Comment || reader.TokenType == JsonToken.None) && reader.Read())
            ;
        return reader;
    }
}
```

Then, make a concrete version that only deserializes list entries of type `Machine1` as follows:

```
public class Machine1ListConverter<TMachineInfo> : JsonListItemTypeInferringConverterBase<TMachineInfo> where TMachineInfo : IMachineInfo
{
    protected override bool TryInferItemType(Type objectType, JToken json, out Type type)
    {
        var obj = json as JObject;
        if (obj != null && obj.GetValue("powerWatts", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) != null)
        {
            type = typeof(Machine1);
            return true;
        }
        type = null;
        return false;
    }
}
```

And finally deserialize your JSON string as follows:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Converters = { new Machine1ListConverter<IMachineInfo>() },
};
var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<IMachineInfo>>(jsonString, settings);
```

Of if you want to deserialize to a concrete `List<Machine1>` do:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Converters = { new Machine1ListConverter<Machine1>() },
};
var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Machine1>>(jsonString, settings);
```

Notes:

- The converter needs to be applied to the overall collection instead of the collection items because [`JsonConverter.ReadJson`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter_ReadJson.htm) has no ability to skip the token currently being read and prevent its return value from being added to the containing object.
- To deserialize only the items of type `Machine2` you could similarly create `Machine2ListConverter` in which `TryInferItemType()` checks for the presence of `dbm`.
- To deserialize you are calling

  ```
  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Machine1>>(@"C/Path/jsonfile", settings);
  ```

  But [`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject Method (String, JsonSerializerSettings)`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject_1.htm) deserializes a JSON string, not a named file.  To deserialize from a file see *[Deserialize JSON from a file](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeWithJsonSerializerFromFile.htm)*.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6zVGbi).